# Magento loop through collection + tier prices extraction

Tags: mysql, magento, mage

I need to loop through all categories and then extract products for each category. Actually, I need to build a table with product data per category. I also need to extract existing tier prices, because I loop through configurable products only.

```
<?php

require 'app/Mage.php';
$app = Mage::app('default'); // Mage_Core_Model_App

$ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
foreach ($ids as $categoryId) {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    echo $category->getName() . ' <br/>';
    $products = $category->getProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id',array('eq'=>'configurable'));
    foreach ($products as $tmp) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($tmp->getId());
        echo $product->getName() . '  ' . $product->getSku() . ' ' .  $product->getPrice() .  ' <br/>';
    }
}
```

What I don't know is how to print all available product attributes of `$product` . For example, I don't know the name of attribute that contains product quantity and can't call it using magic _get method.

And the last thing, is how to extract all existing tier prices from this product? Do they already stored in the `$product` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Price from product you can get using magic _get, like $product->getPrice().
 Or $product->getData('price'), $product->getData('name'), $product->getData();

Gl on that